# Tell Proguard to keep annotation on methods

Tags: java, android, annotations, proguard

I'm using my own annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Loggable { }
```

and obfuscate using Proguard. I use the `-keepattributes *Annotation*` 
in the Proguard configuration to keep the annotations.

At runtime, when I retrieve the annotation from an *annotated class* using `someClass.getAnnotation(Loggable.class)` everything works - I retrieve a non-null instance of my annotation.

However, when I want to apply the same to an *annotated method* of some class, I retrieve null from `someMethod.getAnnotation(Loggable.class)`.

Is Proguard removing the annotations from methods? How do I tell it not to do so?

I'm using Proguard 4.7.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `keepclassmembers` parameter:

```
-keepclassmembers class ** {
  @com.yourpackage.Loggable public *;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but won't this result in keeping the name of the method which has been annotated? I don't want that, I just need to keep the annotation on that method, not the method's name.

Comment: @NumberFour No, there is another parameter to keep methods names. I would recommend you to decompile obfuscated code and just look how it works. It helps to understand `proguard` params much more better rather than even just reading documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and works nicely. You're right that the Proguard documentation is sometimes too vague.