# Java protected method is callable through reflection in debug but not in release Gradle build type

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I just fixed a curious bug, but I am not sure how it was working in the first place. I am using a [TinyBus](https://github.com/beworker/tinybus) even bus in my app. Please consider the following code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class MainFragment extents Fragment {
    ...

    //Event bus annotation
    @Subscribe
    protected void startTutorial(StartTutorial startTutorialEvent) {
        //show tutorial
    }

    ...
}
```

`MainFragment` is wired up to receive events properly. I wouldn't expect the above code to work though, because the `#startTutorial` method is declared `protected`. This is an except from code TinyBus uses to register the methods with `@Subscribe` annotation:

```
public ObjectsMeta(Object obj) {
    final Method[] methods = obj.getClass().getMethods();
    ..
    Subscribe ann;
    for (Method method : methods) {
        ...
        ann = method.getAnnotation(Subscribe.class);
        if (ann != null) {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Full [source code is here](https://github.com/beworker/tinybus/blob/master/tinybus/src/main/java/de/halfbit/tinybus/impl/ObjectsMeta.java). 
As we can see, it uses `#getMethods` to get all the class methods to iterate over and find ones with relevant annotation. Now according to Java docs, `#getMethods` does the following:

> Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the public
>   member methods of the class or interface represented by this Class
>   object, including those declared by the class or interface and those
>   inherited from superclasses and superinterfaces. Array classes return
>   all the (public) member methods inherited from the Object class. The
>   elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any
>   particular order. This method returns an array of length 0 if this
>   Class object represents a class or interface that has no public member
>   methods, or if this Class object represents a primitive type or void.

Here's the [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods()).

It's pretty clear that it should only return an array or *public* methods.

Now with all that background out of the way, **here's the question: how come my `MainFragment` code worked when my app was build for debugging but stopped working when it was build for production**? I was able to reproduce it by making my `build.gradle` file look like this:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false 
        shrinkResources true
    }
    ...
}
```

Once the app was installed, it no longer worked. Changing the accessor of `MainFragment#startTutorial` to `public` fixed it in locally and in production. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is that method called from anywhere else? Any chance ProGuard is eliminating it?

Comment: It isn't. So if it's removed, that might explain it not working in prod. But what about a `protected` method getting through `getMethods` call that's only supposed to get public methods?

Comment: Can you confirm Proguard keep the annonation on methods? @see http://stackoverflow.com/q/30260636

Comment: @beckyang yes i have `-keepattributes *Annotation*` in the ProGuard file

Comment: Did you read the answer and try that solution?

Comment: @beckyang I have resolved the issue, as stated above. I am looking for an explanation of why it was working in the debug mode.