# Button onClick doesn't go back to another activity - Android

Tags: java, android

In my sign up page, I have a button that on click takes to the Sign in activity. But I'm not sure what the button is not working on click.

This is my button in the `activity_signup.xml`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:text="Already registerd? Log in here"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

And here in the `SignUpActivity.java`, I'm trying to add a onClcik method to open the `LoginActivity.java`. But it's not working.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnLogin:
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            break;
    }
}
```

Can you please suggest me what I'm doing wrong, why this button is not working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add the attribute `android:onClick="onClick" ` in your xml layout in the `Button` view.  BTW,  you might want to change that to something like `android:onClick="myButtonOnClick" ` and of course change the method name accordingly

Comment: the way I usally did it was to add abuuton then add a on click listener to that button and then overide the on click for that button and finish at the end

Comment: Can you also put the java code where u are calling setOnClickListener...

Comment: Thanks, @Barns. It solves the problem. Can you please post it and an answer? I'd be able to mark it as correct answer then.

Comment: @Ashonko Although this resovles the issue, there are a few issues with this approach as mentioned in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593014/why-does-a-protected-androidonclick-method-in-activity-actually-work

It is thus a better idea to either do it the way by implementing an interface or directly attaching an onClickListener.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to implement `View.OnClickListener` interface in your Activity.
Simply modify this line:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

note the implements View.OnClickListener part.

Another approach to the same would be to set an onClickListener on the button itself as follows:

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //your logic here
        }
    });
```

Please mark as resolved if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should write this line of code in the end of the onCreate method instead of your void:-

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        onBackPressed();

    }
});
```

And also you can use `finish();` instead of `onBackPressed();` and what do you want after `finish();`, 
`onBackPressed();` do what currently android backbutton does.

Comment: Although this  is correct and certainly an approach to try, it doesn't answer OP's question entirely. In this case all he needed to do was implement an onClickListener interface.